# Why doesn't this work? (Pythagorean triplet)

Tags: java

```
public class Problem9 {

    public static boolean isTriplet( int a, int b, int c ){
        if( a*a + b*b == c*c && a < b && b < c )
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }

    public static boolean isEqual( int a, int b, int c ){
        int z = a + b + c;
        if( z == 1000 )
            return true;   
        else 
            return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        for( int a=0; a < 200; a++ ){
            for( int b=0; b < 200; b++ ){
                for( int c=0; c < 200; c++ ){
                    if( isEqual(a,b,c) && isTriplet(a,b,c))
                        System.out.print( a +" "+ b + " "+ c );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Shouldnt this work??
I can't figure out why this is not working.
Both methods work alone but it still is not printing out anything when i run it.

Comment: `int z = a + b + c;` should actually be `int z = a * b * c;`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: `199+199+199` never gives you a `1000`.

Comment: Your `isEqual()` method does not seem to serve any purpose.  Why do you think you even need it?  The reason you are getting no output is because there are no triplets satisfying `isTriplet` whose sum is also 1000.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For your next question about a program that doesn’t work, please specify (1) how your program was intended to work and (2) precisely in what way the observed behaviour differs. Without this information, your question can be quite obscure and impossible to answer, and will also receive downvotes and likely get closed. See you around.

Comment: As an aside, another way to ensure `a < b` would be in the loop like `for( int b = a + 1; b < 200; b++ )`. Similarly `c = b + 1`.

Comment: Note: if you know that `a + b + c == 1000` you don't need to find `c` by brute force as you know that `c` must be `1000 - a - b`

Answer (score 5):

With `a`, `b` and `c` always being less than 200, `a + b + c` will always be less than 600 and thus never equal to 1000. So `isEqual` returns `false`. That’s enough that `isEqual(a,b,c) && isTriplet(a,b,c)` is false. So if your program prints nothing, it works. :-)

Comment: This is perfect answer. And... also, I think this is not StackOverflow but MathOverflow LMAO

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find a triplet that satisfies both `isEqual(a,b,c)` AND `isTriplet(a,b,c)`, you'll have to increase the range of your loops.

Changing the loops to:

```
for(int a=0; a < 1000; a++ ){
    for(int b=0; b < 1000; b++ ){
        for(int c=0; c < 1000; c++ ){
            if( isEqual(a,b,c) && isTriplet(a,b,c))
                System.out.print( a +" "+ b + " "+ c );
        }
    }
}
```

will result in a single triplet:

```
200 375 425
```

Answer (score 0):

200+200+200 =600 which will never be equal to 1000 as in program So it wont give any output ! So it works without any output !